# My java launcher crashes when display SplashScreen with JDK7 on MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, awt, splash-screen

I'm writing a java launcher using JNI on MacOSX, to display a SplashScreen and AWT window. I have almost finished the program, that it runs with JDK6 successfully, but it will crash with JDK7 if SplashScreen shown.

The whole program is:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

typedef jint (JNICALL * FARPROC_JNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);

int JavaMain();
void ShowSplashWindow();

#define USEJDK6 0

int main()
{
    ShowSplashWindow();

    // start java in a new thread
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_t vmthread;
    pthread_create(&vmthread, &thread_attr, (void *(*)(void*))JavaMain, NULL);

    // start run loop
    CFRunLoopSourceContext sourceContext = {
        .version = 0, .info = NULL, .retain = NULL, .release = NULL,
        .copyDescription = NULL, .equal = NULL, .hash = NULL,
        .schedule = NULL, .cancel = NULL, .perform = NULL };
    CFRunLoopSourceRef sourceRef = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(NULL, 0, &sourceContext);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), sourceRef,  kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    CFRelease(sourceRef);
}

// the old main to run java
int JavaMain()
{
#if USEJDK6
    // load JDK with MacOSX
    void * handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libserver.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
#else
    // --- or SUN JDK 1.7 ---
    void * handle = dlopen("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
#endif

    // get JNI_CreateJavaVM
    FARPROC_JNI_CreateJavaVM FN_JNI_CreateJavaVM = (FARPROC_JNI_CreateJavaVM)dlsym(handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    if(FN_JNI_CreateJavaVM == NULL) FN_JNI_CreateJavaVM = (FARPROC_JNI_CreateJavaVM)dlsym(handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl");

    // Start JVM
    JavaVMOption * options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    memset(options, 0, sizeof(JavaVMOption) * 1);
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version            = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args.nOptions           = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
    vm_args.options            = options;

    JavaVM * pJvm = NULL;
    JNIEnv * pEnv = NULL;

    int result = FN_JNI_CreateJavaVM(&pJvm, (void**)&pEnv, &vm_args);

    // class
    jclass clazz = pEnv->FindClass("test/HelloWorld");
    if(clazz == NULL) {
        pEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
        pEnv->ExceptionClear();
        return 1;
    }

    // method
    jmethodID main = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jclass stringClass = pEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jobjectArray java_argv = pEnv->NewObjectArray(0, stringClass, NULL);
    pEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, main, java_argv);

    // close
    pJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    pJvm->DestroyJavaVM();

    return 0;
}

typedef int (*SplashLoadMemory_t)(void* pdata, int size);
typedef void (*SplashInit_t)(void);
typedef int (*SplashLoadFile_t)(const char* filename);

void ShowSplashWindow()
{
#if USEJDK6
    // load JDK with MacOSX
    void * handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libsplashscreen.jnilib", RTLD_LAZY);
#else
    // --- or SUN JDK 1.7 ---
    void * handle = dlopen("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libsplashscreen.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
#endif

    SplashInit_t SplashInit = (SplashInit_t)dlsym(handle, "SplashInit");
    SplashLoadMemory_t SplashLoadMemory = (SplashLoadMemory_t)dlsym(handle, "SplashLoadMemory");
    SplashLoadFile_t SplashLoadFile = (SplashLoadFile_t)dlsym(handle, "SplashLoadFile");

    SplashInit();
    SplashLoadFile("test/s.jpg");
}
```

Environments:

1. My OS is MacOSX 10.8.
2. The JDK6 is shipped with System, maybe installed from App Store, it has 2 cores (both 32bits and 64bits).
3. The JDK7 is downloaded from oracle.com, it has only one core of 64bits.
4. The program is compiled by LLVM compiler in Xcode command tool.
5. The program is compiled into 64 bits of program.

The program result:

1. If `#define USEJDK6 1` to use JDK6, whether show SplashScreen or not, the program will run successfully.
2. If `#define USEJDK6 0` to use JDK7, the program will crash if show SplashScreen.
3. If `#define USEJDK6 0` to use JDK7, if remove the `ShowSplashWindow();` at the beginning, the program will run successfully.

The error message is `SIGSEGV (0xb)`, the stack is:

```
Stack: [0x00007fff56715000,0x00007fff56f15000],  sp=0x00007fff56f13b80,  free space=8186k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x3998]  +[ThreadUtilities getJNIEnv]+0x5b
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x1a77]  -[NSApplicationAWT registerWithProcessManager]+0x7c
C  [libosxapp.dylib+0x1493]  -[NSApplicationAWT init]+0x8c
C  [AppKit+0xf1864]  +[NSApplication sharedApplication]+0x8f
C  [libsplashscreen.dylib+0x796d]  __SplashInitPlatform_block_invoke_1+0x2d
C  [libdispatch.dylib+0x5f01]  _dispatch_call_block_and_release+0xf
C  [libdispatch.dylib+0x20b6]  _dispatch_client_callout+0x8
C  [libdispatch.dylib+0x70c8]  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF+0x113
C  [CoreFoundation+0x35b4c]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x66c
C  [CoreFoundation+0x350e2]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x122
C  [CoreFoundation+0x43dd1]  CFRunLoopRun+0x61
C  [launcherV3+0x159e]  main+0xee
C  [libdyld.dylib+0x27e1]  start+0x0
```

Anyone can help me how to show SplashScreen correctly with JDK7 on MacOSX? Anyone can point it out where is wrong in my program?

You can download the program here:

- http://www.playcoding.com/sites/playcoding/files/launchers.zip (the `launcherV3`)
- The crash log is here: http://www.playcoding.com/sites/playcoding/files/hs_err_pid241.log

Comment: Is your C code compiled for a 32 or 64 bits processor? JRE7 is 64 bits only on OS X.

Comment: Thanks to @Valentin, then I will now add this information

Comment: I want to know if that JRE actually runs on your system (just covering the obvious). Thus, are you able to run `java -version` on the command line such that it responds with `java version "1.7.0_45"`?

Comment: Thanks to @einnocent, sure, I have installed both 1.6 and 1.7.0_45. I can list all JRE by `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, there are 3 lines, 1.6 has 2 architecture, while 1.7 has one. Without SplashScreen, both 1.6 and 1.7 can run.

Comment: No java exception then?

Comment: can you run it with a try-catch block on showSplashWindow?

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to do is show a splash screen then maybe there's a simpler answer, by way of a workaround. Apparently you can [show a splash screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) upon application load by doing:

```
java -splash:filename.gif MainClass
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm writing my own launcher like `java` does, not to use `java`. I want to know how the `java` is implemented.